# Using limits to solve $ f(x^2 + f(y)) = f(xy) $ when we don't know that $f$ is continuous

Tags: limits, continuity, functional-equations

Problem: find all $f$ such that $f(x^2 + f(y)) = f(xy)$  $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

My approach:
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f((x/n)^2 + f(yn)) = f(xy) \rightarrow \textbf{f(x) = k}$

But we don't know whether the limit actually exists at $\infty$. Does anyone have any idea about what can be done?

Comment: Well, taking $x=0$ tells us that $f\circ f (y)=f(0)$ so at least $f$ is constant on its image.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut it's from a 2018 Canadian mathematics camp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm assuming the function maps real numbers to real numbers.)

Let $k=f(0)$. Taking $y=0$ in the given equation tells us
$$f(x^2+k)=k.$$
In particular, since the range of the function $x\mapsto x^2+k$ is the interval $[k,\infty)$, we have
$$\tag{$\star$}f(z)=k\text{ for all }z\geq k.$$
Now, take any real $t$. Let $y\geq\max(k,0)$, and apply the given equation to $x=t/y$ to get
$$f\left(\frac{t^2}{y^2}+f(y)\right)=f(t).$$
By $(\star)$, $f(y)=k$, and so, since $t^2/y^2\geq 0$, $t^2/y^2+f(y)\geq k$. This means that, by $(\star)$ again, the left side of the above equation equals $k$. So $f(t)=k$, as desired.

---

We can think of this solution as using the continuity of $x^2$ as opposed to the continuity of $f$, which isn't given. The substitution $y=0$ allows us to show that $f$ is constant on a long interval, and the rest is just using the equation somewhat naively to transport this property to all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks. I was just wondering whether we could use limits at all here.

Comment: @David I'd guess that if you can prove something that allows you to use limits at all, you'd already be able to prove that $f$ is constant. Often the difficulty in solving functional equations lies in the possibility of "pathological" solutions rather than standard-looking ones.